# Laravel Display a record details while grouped by year or month

Tags: sql, laravel, group-by

I just moved to the laravel framework and am starting to migrate some legacy sites and I have hit a problem with SQL or blade - dunno which.

I have to display a load of rows 'sports classes' which are grouped by year and then month. each needs to show attendance etc.

I am unsure which way to proceed.
I am able to display all rows and sort by date - easy squeezy
I am able to groupBy year AND month - fiddly but sorted it.
These are all displayed in an accordian. 
Click the month - the individual rows drop down - you get the idea

I can get a number of rows per month/year
What I am unable to figure out is how to actually display the rows.

The groupBy is this:

```
$LinkClasses = DB::table('classes_lists')
->select('id, class, teacher, size')
->select(DB::raw('YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) AS month, MONTHNAME(date) AS month_name, COUNT(*) post_count'))
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
```

Comment: Thanks Kara. - Tired dude. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the code you provided is within your controller, then you can append `->get()` after your last `->orderBy()`.  This will return a Collection.  You can then do whatever you want with the Collection (http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html), including conversion to an array using `->toArray()`, but I think it would be best to utilize the Eloquent ORM if possible.

Anyway, once you have it in the format you want, just pass it to the view like so:

```
return view('your.view', compact('LinkClasses'));
```

Then, inside the `your.view` blade template, you can access this by using the following:

```
@foreach ($LinkClasses as $currentRow)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $currentRow['id'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $currentRow['class'] }}</td>
    <td> ... </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Best guess I can offer without seeing the blade template to get a better idea of what you're doing. Hope that helps!

**UPDATE BASED ON OP FEEDBACK:**

Since you are only receiving a single record, it seems as though the issue lies in your query.  I suggest you simplify your query to fetch all records and then do your sorting within an array.  Something like this in your controller:

```
$allClasses = DB::table('classes_lists')->all();
foreach ($allClasses as $currentClass) {
    $yearMonth = date('Y-m', $currentClass['date']);
    $classesByYearMonth[$yearMonth][] = $currentClass;
}
ksort($classesByYearMonth);

/* now you have an array of all classes sorted by year-month like this:
// $classesByYearMonth[2014-01] = array(
//     [0] => array(1, 'class name', 'teacher name', 23),
//     [1] => array(2, 'another class', 'different teacher', 25),
//     ...
// );
//
// $classesByYearMonth[2014-02] = ...
*/

return view('your.view', compact('classesByYearMonth'));
```

Then, inside your blade template:

```
@foreach ($classesByYearMonth as $yearMonth => $classListArray)
    Found {{ sizeof($classListArray) }} classes for {{ $yearMonth }}
    @foreach ($classListArray as $currentClass)
        <div>
            <div>ID: {{ $currentClass['id'] }}</div>
            <div>Class: {{ $currentClass['class'] }}</div>
            <div>Teacher: {{ $currentClass['teacher'] }}</div>
            <div>Size: {{ $currentClass['size'] }}</div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I will leave it to you to fix the formatting to make your accordion work. But hopefully that will get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for the advice there is a '->get( ); but i was tired and in the pasting it seemed to have become lost in the ether.
Gonna give your thing a try and fight it [as always! :)] till i get the right way working.

Comment: Thanks again. Will post updates and frustrations later Cheers.

Comment: However i am afraid no joy.

Comment: i am still trying with L4.2 but dont seem to get anywhere. Tons of errors when i use the code.

Comment: `$LinkClasses = DB::table('classes_lists')
->select('id, class, teacher, size')
->select(DB::raw('YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) AS month, MONTHNAME(date) AS month_name, COUNT(*) post_count'))
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
 ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get(); ` - that was the original

Comment: `<!--@foreach ($LinkClasses as $Link)  
<div class="panel panel-primary">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
   <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_{{{$Link->month}}}{{{$Link->year}}}">
{{{$Link->month_name }}} {{{$Link->year}}}  - {{{$Link->post_count}}} Classes</a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse_{{$Link->month}}{{$Link->year}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">    <p>{{{$Link->post_count}}} Classes in here</p>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach`

Comment: The code above returns a single record of the year - month - month name and the total classes int that month. I did a vardump and checked what actually being returned and its not all records just the ones requested from the DB governed by the groupBy - what i am attempting unsucessfully to do is to display a header something like -- 2014-novermber and then underneath a list of classes that happened in this time period. my original code is almost 10 years old works great for procedural... and does the job. cant get my head around turning it laravel.

Comment: @user4839716 I have updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

DNoe - thank you so much.
Your reply put me on exactly the right track.
I had to mod some bits due to laravel ambiguities and add the strtotime but the logic was all there.

```
foreach ($allClasses as $currentClass) {
$ym = $currentClass['date']; 
$yearMonth = date("Y-m",strtotime($ym));
    $classesByYearMonth[$yearMonth][] = $currentClass;
}
krsort($classesByYearMonth);

return View::make('classes.index', compact('classesByYearMonth'));
```

The css is simple from here.
I owe you some beers. And thanks for helping me take my head from my butt!

Send me a pm and i would be very very happy to forward beer donation :o

Great work and thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, part of the problem was that the results were throwing an stdObject rather than an array.

Being able to compare your code with my own has enabled me to create a dbquery with multiple joins from which meaningfull data is selected and then converted to an array.

```
$classes = DB::table('table2')
->join('table1', 'table2.id', '=', 'table1.id2' )
->join('table3', 'table1.id3', '=', 'table3.id' )

->orderBy('classes_lists.date','DESC')
->get(array('table1.id', 'teacher', 'date', 'size', 'students', 'fname', 'classname', 'table1.notes'));

$cfr = count($classes);

foreach($classes as $object)
{
$arrays[] =  (array) $object;
}

foreach ($arrays as $currentClass){
$ym = $currentClass['date']; 
$yearMonth = date("Y-m",strtotime($ym));
$clazByYearMonth[$yearMonth][] = $currentClass;
}

krsort($clazByYearMonth);
```

This was the output into blade:
*Not formatted :*

```
@foreach ($clazByYearMonth as $yearMonth => $classListArray)
Found {{ sizeof($classListArray) }} classes for {{ $yearMonth }}
    @foreach ($classListArray as $currentClass)
<div>
date: {{ $currentClass['date'] }} | class: {{ $currentClass['classname'] }} | Size: {{ $currentClass['size'] }} Teacher: {{ $currentClass['fname'] }} |
</div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```