# Laravel 4.2 - rows groupby display

Tags: laravel, group-by, row, laravel-blade

This is a Laravel problem - I tried to ask earlier but I am not sure I expressed myself well.

I have a bunch of rows and I would like to group the rows by year and month in descending order and then display all rows contained in each grouped month going backwards in time.

I have an old code of ten years which does the job well - but I am moving it to Laravel and I am doing okay on almost all queries and views but just cannot get this to work.

The problem is that it does not display the years and months in descending order and that I am unable to pass each row contained in the month grouping to the view.

I have tried `arrays/collections/blade@foreach` and I am a bit out of solution now, so I humbly request assistance!

Comment: Can you past how you do it in laravel and what query do you expect?

Comment: I updated the answer over on the duplicate of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907542/laravel-display-a-record-details-while-grouped-by-year-or-month)  Hopefully that gets you going...